# Jackson XML unmarshalling and abstract classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson

I'm trying to unmarshal the following XML using Jackson 2.4.0 `XmlMapper`:

```xml
<root>
  <a/>
  <b/>
</root>
```

...and the following POJO

```java
class Root {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "a", value = POJO_A.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "b", value = POJO_B.class)
    })
    public final List<AbstractPOJO> objects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I've also tried with JAXB `@XmlElements` annotations with the same result, which is:

```
Unrecognized field "a" (class Root), not marked as ignorable (1 known properties: "objects"])
```

So it seems that Jackson thinks my list is called "objects" instead of "a" and "b". Normally I fix that by using `@JsonProperty("newName")` but in this case I expected that to be handled by the `@JsonSubtypes` or `@XmlElements` annotations.

As I cannot modify the input XML, is there anything else I can do, either with Jackson, Jackson XML or JAXB annotations?

Update: Forgot to say, the problem is deserializing to the same collection (because I need to keep the order and they can be mixed). Doing it in separate fields works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

When I was trying peeskillet answer and changed Jackson for JAXB unmarshaller, using `@XmlElements`/`@XmlElementRefs` worked (`@XmlAnyElement` did not for some reason, I was getting a list of `ElementNSImpl` instead of my own classes).

It will be nice to have this working with Jackson, but in the meantime, this is the way to make this work.

UPDATE:

What I did was:

```java
class Root {
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "a", type = PojoA.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "b", type = PojoB.class)
    })
    public final List<AbstractPOJO> objects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I also added a `@XmlRootElement(name = "a")` to `PojoA`, but I think it's not used when you have `@XmlElements`

Comment: Yeah this is probably more semantically correct with your domain :-) +1

Comment: did it the same way with XmlElements and JAXM marshalling.

Answer (score -1):

> "As I cannot modify the input XML, is there anything else I can do, either with Jackson, Jackson XML or JAXB annotations?"

I'm not too familiar with Jackson's Xml features. But with the JAXB [`Unmarshaller`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) and a little change to your annotations, this can be achieved.

For your `List<AbstractPojo>` you can use the [`@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html).

With [`lax = true`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html#lax%28%29):

> If true, when an element matches a property marked with `XmlAnyElement` is known to `JAXBContext` (for example, there's a class with XmlRootElement that has the same tag name, or there's `XmlElementDecl` that has the same tag name), the unmarshaller will eagerly unmarshal this element to the JAXB object, instead of unmarshalling it to DOM

Which basically means that if we annotate `PojoA` and `PojoB` with `@XmlRootElement` and pass the element name as the `name` attribute (`@XmlRootElement(name = "a")`), by definition, this should work.

Let's give it a shot:

```
public abstract class AbstractPojo {
    // note this class is not annotated. It will be known in the context
    // as we're explicitly using the type int the Root class
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
public class PojoA extends AbstractPojo {
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "b")
public class PojoB extends AbstractPojo {
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<AbstractPojo> objects;

    public List<AbstractPojo>  getObjects() {
        if (objects == null) {
            objects = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return this.objects;
    }
}
```

Using the following xml file to test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a/> <b/> <b/> <a/> <a/> <b/> <b/>
</root>
```

And the following test program

```
public class JaxbTest {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "test.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        File f = new File(FILE_NAME);
        Root root = (Root)unmarshaller.unmarshal(f);
        List<AbstractPojo> list = root.getObjects();

        for (AbstractPojo p : list) {
            System.out.print( p instanceof PojoA ? "a " : "b ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }
}
```

We get the result we're looking for.

> `a b b a a b b`  // along with the xml file content we marshal for testing

---

Here are some good resources:

- [JAXB tutorial](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/index.html)
- [Oracle JAXB tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)
- [@XmlAnyElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html)
- [Blaise Doughan's blog is always a good resource](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html)

---

**UPDATE**

> Ok I see why you were getting `ElementNSImpl`. This doesn't work for me, I'm getting ElementNSImpl objects. Do you know what's happening?

Yea I see what's happening. Firstly, I compiled an xsd with xjc, and it created an ObjectFactory for me, which declared the elements. That's why it way working for me.

If you don't do this, then you should explicitly put the `PojoA` and `PojoB` into the context.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, PojoA.class, PojoB.class);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm getting `ElementNSImpl` objects. Do you know what's happening? I'll add my solution in the meantime

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE**. Also would you mind posting how you implemented this with `@XmlElements/@XmlElementRefs`. I was not able to get it to work.